# Method naming conventions and PMD

Tags: regex, rules, pmd, static-code-analysis

When I run PMD analysis on my code, I get the following message:

```
Name `'END_METHOD'` must match pattern 

'^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
```

`END_METHOD` is of type `private final`. Should it include special character ? or lower case character ?

Answer (score 1):

The message is telling you the name should start with a lowercase character.

The convention that PMD is enforcing here is that only static final variables are named in all caps, while variables local to a method (final or not) use [camel-case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). Methods also use camel-case.

[`a-z`] means one lowercase alphabetic character.

`[a-zA-Z0-9]*` means zero or more characters, each of which can be lowercase, uppercase, or numeric (no special characters or underscores).

Together the regex says the string should start with one lowercase character followed by 0 or more alphanumeric characters.